# Curl multiple data in one POST command

Tags: web-services, post, curl

Can anyone tell me if I can (in the command line) issue a POST command that contains a file and other parameters?

I am trying to do something like:

```
curl -X POST -F "key=myKey&file=@myfile.txt"  http://localhost:8080/myRestService/
```

I am really new in this domain, so excuse me for my basic question.
But it does not seems to work well. Any suggestion?
Tank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use -d param

check a man page  http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file
>   name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data
>   from stdin. The contents of the file must already be URL-encoded.
>   Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named
>   'foobar' would thus be done with --data @foobar.

Try to specify a full path to your file.